# How to build a regular expression that matches a Facebook, Google or Twitter email/nickname validation pattern?

Tags: regex, facebook, twitter, google-api, email-validation

In a web app, if a user is allowed to signup via Google, Facebook or Twitter and if the username of a user is formed in the following manner:

- if authenticated with Twitter - take Twitter nickname;
- if authenticated with Google or Facebook - take the part of the email before the @ sign

and if I want to use a regular expression for the format of the username, basically I need something like:

```
/\A(twitter_pattern|google_pattern|facebook_pattern)\z/
```

where

- `twitter_pattern` is the pattern, used by Twitter to validate nicknames;
- `google_pattern` is the pattern, used by Google to validate the part of the email before @.
- `facebook_pattern` - the pattern Facebook uses to validate the part of the email before @.

In this regard I have two questions:

1. How do I find out the exact regex patterns, that each of these providers uses?
2. How am I supposed to keep this in sync? Am I supposed to check regularly, that they have not changed these patterns at some point?

Comment: Q1: You pretty much can't. It is probably done server-side, and so you cannot access the code. The only way to work it out would be entering millions of different nicknames, systematically, and using the data you recieve from that to work it out. Q2: A bit broad for StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Why would you need to validate this yourself in the first place? You get the data from their respective APIs. so it will be validated according to their rules already. Now where's the need here for you to validate anything again now ...?